# App delegate or rootViewController for osx app login screen?

Tags: macos, swift2

Since there is not much osx ressources out there i face a dilemma.
Either i implement my login screen like i did on ios, using a method on appdelegate to change the first view controller (seems to be tricky on osx though).
Or i can use a root controller which will be attach to the windows controller.

So which is the best practice?
Also seems that getting the window with NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow and setting the contentiewController does not switch the VC attach to the window.

Comment: A comparison of sheets and modal dialogs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Concepts/AboutSheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001043-BABFIBIA

Comment: For the same reason (vc attached do not switch) i put my login view in a rootviewcontroler instead of putting it in appdelegate.
Depending on what you are doing you can present the loginview as a modalsheet.